# jQuery Remove Action and Show an Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the HTML below how could I remove the form action and show an alert if the submit button is clicked?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="reservation-widget-content">
    <form class="resForm" action="https://www.thebookingbutton.com.au/properties" method="get">

        <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Check Availability</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the criteria for removing the form action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Javasrcipt**

'onclick' is the event in javascript which is executed when the element is clicked

```
 <div id="reservation-widget-content">
        <form class="resForm" action="" method="get">

            <button type="submit" id="submit-button" onclick="alert('Success')">Check Availability</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Using Jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit-button").click(function(){
    alert("Success");
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

`return false` will prevent the page from being redirected after alert.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` will prevent default behaviour of submit button and stops the event bubbling up through the DOM.

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(){

 alert('Submit button clicked !');
 return false;

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/19afmk4s/)

return false does combined work of

- event.preventDefault();
- event.stopPropogation();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.resform').removeAttr('action').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('form submitted');
  // rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="reservation-widget-content">
<form class="resForm" action="" method="get">
<button type="button" id="submit-button">Check Availability</button>
</form>
</div>

$('#submit-button').click(function(){
alert('Show something');
});
```

Try this. 
Change the button type to 'button' (now you are using 'submit'. This will submit the form on when button is clicked).